# List size each object take up in System.Runtime.Caching memory cache c#

Tags: c#, caching

I'm using a c# memory cache (System.Runtime.Caching) and it is filling up, and using way more ram than expected.
Is there anyway to list the size that each object in the cache is taking up within the cache

I want to code something similar to this so I can determine which particular item is causing the problem?

```
private void ListSizeOfEachItemInCache()
{
    foreach {var item in Cache.Items}
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(item.Key, item.CacheSize));
    }
}
```

My items are typically classes that contain collections within them, and have a large object graph.  However if I serialize them to disk, using a data contract serializer they don't seem to fill as much space on disk, as they seem to in RAM.  This is leading me to think a file cache, might work better (as the items are being retrieved from a remote database - not even locally).

```
private static readonly MemoryCache Cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

I've seen other questions asking about listing an objects size in memory, but this is different as I want the exact size it is taking up in the memory cache (which I can't assume would be the exact same, maybe it has some other overhead, as the cache needs to know some other data, such as when it was added, it's expiry policy etc)..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah odds are you wont' get an exact number. Best you can do is use reflection to iterate the hierarchy of the object and tally up the size of all the value types using `sizeof`. That still won't tell you an exact size though.

For that example I metioned, you could use some code like this

```
void Main()
{
    var types = new List<object>{
        (byte)1,
        (short)1,
        (int)1,
        (long)1,
        (double)1,
        (decimal)1,
        (float)1,
        "omg afd obj amd",
        "omg afd obj amd omg afd obj amd omg afd obj amd omg afd obj amd omg afd obj amd omg afd obj amd omg afd obj amd ",
        new Exception("Holy Maceral"),
    };

    foreach(var o in types)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Size of {0} == {1}",o.GetType().Name,o.SizeOf());
    }
}
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int SizeOf(this object obj)
    {
        int size = 0;
        if(obj == null)
            return 0;
        Type type = obj.GetType();

        if(type.IsValueType)
        {
            return type.SizeOfType();
        }

        PropertyInfo[] info = type.GetProperties();
        foreach(PropertyInfo property in info)
        {
            if(property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
            {
                var ip = property.GetIndexParameters().First();
                //Console.WriteLine(info);
                var len = (int)info.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "Length" || x.Name == "Count").GetValue(obj);
                for(var i = 0;i<len;i++)
                {
                    size += property.GetValue(obj,new object[1]{i}).SizeOf();
                }
            }
            else if(property.GetGetMethod().ReturnType.IsArray)
            {
                var arr = property.GetGetMethod().Invoke(obj,null);
                foreach(var a in (Array)arr)
                {
                    size+= a.SizeOf();
                }
            }
            else if(property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                var val = property.GetValue(obj,null);
                unsafe
                {
                    size += property.PropertyType.SizeOfType();
                }
            }
            else{
                size += property.GetValue(obj,null).SizeOf();
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    public static int SizeOfType(this Type type)
    {
        if(type.IsValueType == false)
            throw new ArgumentException("type must be value type");

        return Marshal.SizeOf(type);
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Size of Byte == 1
Size of Int16 == 2
Size of Int32 == 4
Size of Int64 == 8
Size of Double == 8
Size of Decimal == 16
Size of Single == 4
Size of String == 19
Size of String == 116
Size of Exception == 36
```

It's not 100% perfect and may not work on every object without some tweaking, but it should do the job to figure out which object is the most offensive.